# What is this line's mean in VSCode source code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, interface, decorator

I found the following code in the VS Code source code.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5da4d93f579f3fadbaf835d79dc47d54c0d6b6b4/src/vs/workbench/contrib/comments/browser/commentsEditorContribution.ts#L166

It seems `ICommentService` is an interface. I think interface can not be a decorator.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators

What is `@ICommentService`?

Answer (score 1):

`ICommentService` is in fact [a decorator function](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5da4d93f579f3fadbaf835d79dc47d54c0d6b6b4/src/vs/workbench/contrib/comments/browser/commentService.ts#L17):

```
export const ICommentService = createDecorator<ICommentService>('commentService');
```

[and an interface](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5da4d93f579f3fadbaf835d79dc47d54c0d6b6b4/src/vs/workbench/contrib/comments/browser/commentService.ts#L34) (like you linked above):

```
export interface ICommentService {
  ...
}
```

It can be both of these things because identifiers in TypeScript can reference both a value (which is used at runtime) as well as a type (which is used when type-checking).